# How to create a Microsoft Teams team using a PowerShell Azure function and the Graph API?

Tags: powershell, rest, azure-functions, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

My ultimate goal is to create a MS Teams team with channels and tabs of applications.
But first, I need to properly format my request. I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
Obviously I found [this topic (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0) Example n°3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0)  that looks promising but I dont know how to use it. I started with the code bellow:

```
$password = "stackexchange"
$login = "stackexchange@stackexchange.onmicrosoft.com"
$ownerEmail = "stackexchange@stackexchange.onmicrosoft.com"
$url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams"   
$securedPassword = convertto-securestring -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $login, $securedPassword   
$GraphAppId = "stackexchange-guid"
$GraphAppSecret = "stackexchange"
$AADDomain = "stackexchange.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-AzureAD -Credential $creds
$userId = (Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $ownerEmail).ObjectId
write-output $userId # Here the userId is actually displayed

Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId $GraphAppId -ClientSecret $GraphAppSecret -AADDomain $AADDomain 
$accessToken = Get-PnPGraphAccessToken

$header = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
}    

$body = @{  
    displayName = "Test"
    "owners@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$userId')"
    "template@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"
    memberSettings = @{
    allowCreateUpdateChannels = $true
    }
    messagingSettings = @{
    allowUserEditMessages = $true
    allowUserDeleteMessages = $true
    }
    funSettings = @{
    allowGiphy = $true
    giphyContentRating = "strict"
    }
}
$Body = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $body    
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $Body -Method 'Post' -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing -Credential $creds
```

I get the following message in my PowerShell terminal :

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid bind property name owners in request.",
        "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-09-03T15:40:53",
        "request-id": "fef8bd7e-3143-4ea9-bcf6-a87702a488b8"
        }
    }
}
At character Line:36 : 5
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Body $Body -Method 'Post' -Headers $ ...
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this all "by hand", I'd suggest looking at the [Graph SDK for PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Graph/0.9.1). It's still 'officially' in beta, but that's this PowerShell SDK, not the Graph itself of course.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I prefer not to use beta version of any products for production environnement because updates could be done leading to a not working code. This is a bad practice. If you know how to properly doing it "by hand" It will be great.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the PS nuget "MicrosoftTeams"

for example:

```
# ===========================================
# this Script creates a new project environment containing:
# - a new TEAMs channel
# ===========================================

Install-Module MicrosoftTeams -Force # -AllowClobber


## parameters
$TeamDisplayName='contoso'
$ProjectName='Contoso-Reporting'

$TEAMS_ChannelName=$ProjectName

## connect to TEAMS
Connect-MicrosoftTeams

## Get the Opslogix TEAM
$team = Get-Team | foreach {if ( $_.DisplayName -eq $TeamDisplayName ) { $_ }}

## create a new project channel
$team | new-TeamChannel -DisplayName $TEAMS_ChannelName
#$team | Get-TeamChannel

## disconnect TEAMS
Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You did not specified the way to actually create the MS Teams team.

Comment: In addition there is not cmdlets to interact with MS Teams tab. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/powershell-script-to-remove-tabs/m-p/161702 and also official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/?view=teams-ps

Comment: You can use the New-Team cmdlet to create a new team.
    
SYNOPSIS
    Note: This cmdlet is currently in Beta.
    
    Creates a new team. The new team will be backed by a new unified group.
   
    
SYNTAX
    New-Team [-AccessType <String>] [-AddCreatorAsMember <Boolean>] [-Alias <String>] [-Classification <String>] [-Description <String>] -DisplayName <String> [<CommonParameters>]
    
    
DESCRIPTION
    Creates a new team with user specified settings, and returns a Group object with a GroupID property.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
"owners@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$userId')"
```

to:

```
members = @(
    @{
      '@odata.type' = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember"
      roles = @(
        'owner'
      )
      'user@odata.bind' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('$userId')"
    }
)
```